# Regex in C# doesn't match when there more than one space or there is comma and space

Tags: c#, regex

I used C# and I would like to match 3 doubles seperated by comma(maybe yes\not) or\and by spaces(maybe yes\not and one or more)

I did:

```
 Regex regex = new Regex(@"\d+[,|\s*]\d+[,|\s*]\d+");
 Match match = regex.Match(mystr.Text);
```

Issue is that the below text isn't match:

**`33   44  55`** (after 33 and after 44 there is two spaces)

Also, the match didn't catch:

**`33, 44, 55`** (after comma there is also one space)

Any advice?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe [`\d+[,\s]+\d+[,\s]+\d+`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cd%2b%5b%2c%5cs%5d%2b%5cd%2b%5b%2c%5cs%5d%2b%5cd%2b&i=33+++44++55%0d%0a33%2c+44%2c+55)?

Comment: Wiktor, if you have an answer to the problem, please post it as an answer.

Comment: But it is not a good answer anyway. I would use a different one, I just want to understand if that is the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex inside brackets are wrong, you may try with this:

```
\d+[,\s]*\d+[,\s]*\d+
```

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this function for you?

```
 (\d{2},?\s+){2}\d{2}
```

It matches 2 digits then zero or one comma, with multiple spaces, and it does it twice and ending with 2 digits?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple solution for you

```
string nmbrs = "33  44";
string numberPattern = @"\d+(?=[,\s]*\d+[,\s]*)\d+";
var matches = Regex.Matches(nmbrs, numberPattern);
List<int> numbersList = new List<int>();
foreach (var match in matches)
{
    numbersList.Add(int.Parse(match.ToString()));
}
```